# I have made a c# console app, how do I run it out of VB?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I am new to coding, just started college, I have made a very simple coin flipper in Visual c# express, it is a console application, how do I now run this application without having to enter VB and click the play button?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aBoeS2dkPg4

Comment: You mean VS right? VS=Visual Studio the IDE, VB=Visual Basic, a programming language

Answer (score 2):

If you have compiled the console app, you should have a /bin/debug folder in your application, and there will be an executable (CoinFlipper.exe), which you can run